# Java String split() shows different result on Mac and Windows

Tags: java, string

The test code is:

```
String s = "";
System.out.println(s.split("").length);
```

On Mac and Windows ,the output is 1, but when the string is not empty,like:

```
String s = "1";
System.out.println(s.split("").length);
```

On Mac, the result is still 1,while on Windows, the result has changed to 2.
Both IDE is eclipse.Why does this occur? As Java's purpose is "Write once ,run anywhere".

Comment: Are you using different Java versions? There was some related change in Java 8.

Comment: Don't know `spilt` method. Only `split` :)

Comment: Whats the output of `java -version` on both?